# Eigenvalue and singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix.

Let $\sigma_{\text{min}}(A)$ be the minimal singular value of $A$, and $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A)$ be the minimal eigenvalue of $A$.

Show we have this inequality :

$$\sigma_{\text{min}}(A) < |\lambda_{\text{min}}(A)|$$

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Could you also give the definitions of eigen/singular values you are using ?

Comment: You might want to add a bit of MathJax to your post, by adding \$....\$ around your math.